# How to stop overflow of elements in a multi column in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, multiple-columns

I have created a form with 2 columns which looks like this:
[image]

The Student name is mandatory field. So, when an empty input is required it throws a red text labelled as **Required**. The problem is that when this happens the field name marked as `Student name:` comes to the other column as shown below.
[image]

Here is my css for the same.

```
.formLayout{
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 5%;
}
```

Is there a way to prevent that using the .css only or any workarounds to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put a minimum height of the rows?

If there is a chance to get the error message out, there should be more space.

Something like:

```
display: grid;
grid-template: repeat(2, 100px) / 50% 50%;
column-gap: 5%;
```

Comment: Oh my god. You just saved my day. Had some little modifications made but had it done. Thanks